# Dynamic extended models method not run - PHP

Tags: php, model, module, controller, extends

I wrote a class for module creating. That run correctly except that model object.

Model class :

```
class Model{
    public static  $db;
    protected $_table_name;
    public function __construct() {
        self::$db =& DB::singleton();
    }
    public function get($rows="*",$where=null,$page_no=null,$limit=null,$order_by=null,$table_name=null){
        if(!isset($table_name)||empty($table_name)){
            self::$db->table=$this->_table_name;
        }else{
            self::$db->table=$table_name;
        }
        self::$db->rows = $rows;
        self::$db->limit=$limit;
        self::$db->where=$where;
        self::$db->page_no=$page_no;
        self::$db->order_by=$order_by;
        return self::$db->read();
    }

    public function delete($id,$table){
        self::$db->table = $table;
        self::$db->where ="id='{$id}'";
        self::$db->delete();
        return 1;
    }
    public function drop_table($table){
        self::$db->table=$table;
        self::$db->drop_table();
        return 1;
    }
    public function get_module_name(){
        return $this->_table_name;
    }


    public function set_table($table_name){
        $this->_table_name=$table_name;
    }
}
```

Extended class :

```
class m_publication_categories extends model
{
    protected $_table_name = 'publication_categories'; 
}
```

Controller :

```
class Controller{
    public $db;
    public $model;

    public function __construct(){
        core::$theme->setup();
        $model_class_name = "m_".get_called_class();
        $this->model=new $model_class_name();
    }

    public function listAction(){
        $module_name = $this->model->get_module_name();
        $module_model = new m_modules();

        /**moduleinfo*/
        $module = $module_model->get("*","table_name='{$module_name}'");
        $module = $module[0];
        $module_columns = $module_model->list_fields($module->id);
        $data = $this->model->get();

        print_r($data);die;
        $this->assign('data',$data);
        $this->assign('module_columns' , $module_columns);
        $this->assign('module',$module);
        $this->display('list_module_data','modules');
    }
}
```

I want use model::get method from controller $this->model->get  but that not work correctly. But if i print_r $this->model in controller , return result like that :

```
m_publication_categories Object ( [_table_name:protected] => publication_categories )
```

This means code in extends model class, but why not enter main model class  ?

thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the `Model` class you included is the correct one? What happens if you instantiate `Model` and `print_r()` it?

Comment: First step i run controller->listAction, and that run m_publication_categories model ( this is extend from model class ) and i create m_publication_categories model in controller->__construct, and i use in controller->listAction with m_publication_categories->get(). get method was write in main model class. Edit: but get method not work.

Comment: What do you mean by get method not working?

Comment: function get() {} in class model{} not work on m_publication_categories extends model(){} class declare from class controller{}